# neo4j script file format - is there any?

Tags: neo4j, file-format

I would like to predefine some graph data for neo4j and be able to load it, maybe via a console tool. I'd like it to be precisely the same as MySQL CLI and `.sql` files. Does anyone know if there exists a file format like `.neo` or `.neo4j`? I couldn't find such thing in the docs...

Comment: What language would this script be written in? Cypher?

Comment: yep - exactly. Just to write queries.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

We usually do .cql or .cypher for script files. You can pipe it to the shell to run it, like so:

```
./neo4j-shell -c < MY_FILE.cypher
```

Michael Hunger was doing some great work on this feature, also, just recently. He got performance up and noise down from the console. I hope it gets into 1.9 release.

Comment: Is there any way to run this from within neo4j-sh? e.g. @myScript.cql ?

Comment: Not that I know of. I'd love to hear of it, though.

Comment: Okay, thanks Wes. You've saved me time that I'd have wasted stubbornly believing there is a way to do it. Hopefully someone will add a feature request :)

Comment: @EveFreeman / @Sridhar-Samobat I've added such a way to neo4j-client, using the `:source` client command (see the alternative answer).

Answer (score 11):

From https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/opencypher/PO5EnspBLs0

1:

> "Sorry for the late reply, but we just wanted to inform you that the **official recommendation is to use `.cypher`**.
>   We'll be formalising this in the style guide soon."

2:

> "In training run by Neo4j, we've historically used .cyp. I believe the preference is to use .cypher, and **.cyp when an extension of 3 chars is required**."

3:

> "Note: **'.cql' is already used for Cassandra** - https://cassandra.apache.org/doc/cql/CQL.html"

**From the above extracts:**
1st preference is `.cypher`
2nd preference is `.cyp`  (1st 3 characters of cypher)
Don't use <s>`.cql`</s>

**More:**

If you need a color coding in notepad++, download the xml given at https://gist.github.com/nicolewhite/b0344ea475852c8c9571 , import it via menu `Language > User Defined Language > Import > Restart the Notepad++, open a file with .cypher that has some cyper query language)`

**Sample cypher is below:**

```
MATCH (:Person {name: "Ann"})        -[:FB_FRIENDS]->    Create (:Person {name: "Dan"})
```

Hope that helps someone.

Answer (score 6):

Using [neo4j-client](https://cleishm.github.io/libneo4j-client/) as the CLI for Neo4j allows for easy evaluation of scripts. There are several ways to work with a script containing multiple cypher commands:

1. You can pipe the script in via standard input, e.g.:

   ```
   neo4j-client -u neo4j -P localhost < my_script.cyp
   ```
2. You can use the command line option `--source` or `-i`, e.g.:

   ```
   neo4j-client -u neo4j -P -i my_script.cyp localhost
   ```
3. You can start an interactive shell, and then source the script:

   ```
   $ neo4j-client localhost
   Username: neo4j
   Password: *****
   neo4j-client 1.2.1.
   Enter `:help` for usage hints.
   Connected to 'neo4j://neo4j@localhost:7687'
   neo4j>
   neo4j> :source my_script.cyp
   ```

The extension `.cyp` is most commonly used for scripts.